# Why does declaring global variables result in application force close

Tags: android, global-variables, main-activity

It works fine when the variables are in onCreate scope, but I need to use the variables in onDestroy scope too so I made it global variables. but then my app force closed when opened.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel (this);
    EditText editText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text_template, null);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Set fullscreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    gamePanel.setLayoutParams(gameParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            300, 100);
    etParams.leftMargin = 200;
    etParams.topMargin = 800;
    editText.setLayoutParams(etParams);

    RelativeLayout content = new RelativeLayout(this);

    content.addView(gamePanel);
    content.addView(editText);

    setContentView(content);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

As seen in the code, I want to use gamePanel and editText as global variables. Any idea how to do this? Or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: because `getLayoutInflater()` can't be used to initiliaze a member variable. Declare  `EditText editText` and initialize it when onCreate is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize yours variables in OnCreate()

```
 GamePanel gamePanel;
    EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gamePanel = new GamePanel (this);
    editText = (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text_template, null);

...}
```

Comment: Thank you. my bad did not realize that. Sorry for duplicate post though.

Comment: It would be better to explain why he has to put initialization code inside the onCreate(), not just say that he should do it.

Comment: Yes you are right, you can propose an update or add it in comment

Comment: Not sure why this got so many upvotes when the OP said, "It works fine when the variables are in onCreate scope"